# Compiler-specific flags in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I would like to specify `linkopts` on a `cc_library` target, but only if the target is built with clang (because gcc doesn't support the flag). How do I go about this?

The specific example in which this need arose is https://pigweed-review.googlesource.com/c/pigweed/pigweed/+/136287 (see also comments on this change). A library produces a warning when linked with clang with the [--warn_backrefs](https://lld.llvm.org/ELF/warn_backrefs.html) flag. This warning can be silenced using `--warn-backrefs-exclude`, but only clang recognizes this flag: adding it unconditionally will lead gcc to report an error.

Apparently, CMake allows handling such compiler-specific flags via `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` and `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_VERSION`. Is there an analogous mechanism in Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Bazel config. Create in the root directory of your workspace (where `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel` is located) a file name `.bazelrc`. You can now define different configs, e.g. `gcc11`, `clang14` or `vs2022`:

```
# GCC 11
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-std=c++20
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Wall
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Werror
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Wno-volatile
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-Wextra


# Clang 14
build:clang14 --cxxopt=-std=c++20
build:clang14 --cxxopt=--warn-backrefs-exclude

# Visual Studio 2022
build:vs2022 --cxxopt=/std:c++20
build:vs2022 --cxxopt=/Zc:__cplusplus
build:vs2022 --enable_runfiles # https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8843
build:vs2022 --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
build:vs2022 --copt=-DNOGDI
build:vs2022 --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
build:vs2022 --host_copt=-DNOGDI
build:vs2022 --define compiler=vs2022
```

Now when you call Bazel you can handover a preferred config, e.g.:

```
bazel build --config=clang14 //...
```

Another way could be to make use of [platforms](https://bazel.build/concepts/platforms).